# Index in a for loop laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a collection with a relationship in Laravel 5.4. I want to loop through it using a **for** loop.
If I do (testing):

```
{{ $application->kids[0]->name }}
{{ $application->kids[1]->name }}
```

everything works.
But if I put index in **kids** array:

```
{{ $application->kids[$i]->name }}
```

it throws a 500 error.
I'm using native php loop: for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){}
What am I missing?

```
`<?php for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) { ?>  `

<input type="text" value="{{ $application->kids[$i]->name }}">   
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can you show your loop

Comment: Don't use native code in views.
Post your model

Comment: Have you tried with blade `@for($i = 0;$i < 2; $i++) ... @endfor` ?

Answer (score 1):

You may be iterating past the length of the $application->kids array and getting an ArrayOutOfBounds Exception. If you want to do a for loop I would suggest doing `for($i = 0; $i < count($application->kids); $i++)`

You may have better luck using a foreach within blade like so:

```
@foreach($application->kids as $kid)
  <input type="text" value="{{$kid->name}}"> 
@endforeach
```

More information on template control structures at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#loops

Comment: Even if it works it does not resolve the user's problem why using index crashes his page

Comment: Thanks. I know about this **foreach**  but I'm trying to figure out what the problem is with **for**   My question is why the iterator doesn't work while plain integer does.

Comment: Ah yes, it may be that you are iterating past the length of the array. So the array may only have 3 elements but you're iterating through 5. Thus hitting an array out of bounds exception. In your .env you can also update `APP_DEBUG` to `true` and see if that gives you more information.

Comment: @chip has solved the problem. While testing I was iterating through more items than I have in my array. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use laravel `foreach` syntax to iterate over your data as

```
@foreach($application->kids as $kid)
  <input type="text" value="{{$kid->name}}"> 
@endforeach
```